# why python selectors module has no event for socket error

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

In `select`,there is a list for error socket or `epoll` has event for `ERROR`

But in `selectors` module just has events for `EVENT_READ` and `EVENT_WRITE`.

therefore，how can I know the error socket without event?

Comment: Are you talking about the [`selectors`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/selectors.html) module?

Comment: @user2357112 Yes I do

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An error on the socket will always result in the underlying socket being signaled as readable (at least). For example, if you are waiting for data from a remote peer, and that peer closes its end of the connection (or abends, which does the same thing), the local socket will get the `EVENT_READ` marking. When you go to read it, you would then get zero bytes (end of file), telling you that the peer is gone (or at least finished sending).

Similarly, if you were waiting to send data and the peer resets the connection, you will get an `EVENT_WRITE` notification. When you then go to attempt a send, you will get an error from the send (which, in python, means an exception).

The only thing you lose here from `select` is the ability to detect exceptional conditions: the `xlist` from `select.select` or `POLLPRI` from `select.poll`. If you needed those, you would need to use the lower-level `select` module directly. (Priority/out of band data is not commonly used so this is not an unreasonable choice.)

So the simplified interface provided by `selectors` really loses no "error" information. If there is an error on the socket that would have caused a `POLLERR` return from `select.poll`, a RST from the remote, say, you will get a `EVENT_READ` or `EVENT_WRITE` notification and whatever error occurred will be re-triggered as soon as you attempt `send` or `recv`.

A good rule of thumb to keep in mind with `select`, `poll` and friends is that a result indicating "readable" *really* means "will not block if you attempt to read". It doesn't mean you will actually get data back from the read; you may get an error instead.

Likewise for "writable": you may not be able to send data, but attempting the write won't block.